# Force sum of weights in vector to be 100

Tags: c++, vector, double

I need to populate a vector so that it holds a sum of weights, where the sum **must** be 100. In other words, the number of items is equal to the divisor, and its values are the quotient, to ensure **(force)** the sum of the vector to equal 100.

Something like this: 100/3=3.333333...

```
vector[0]=33.33
vector[1]=33.34
vector[2]=33.33
```

The sum of this needs to be exactly 100 (some sort of selective rounding?)
Another example: 100/6 = 16.66666667

```
vector[0]=16.67
vector[1]=16.67
vector[2]=16.66
vector[3]=16.67
vector[4]=16.67
vector[5]=16.66
```

I've seen something like this done in grocery stores where something on sale might be 3 for $11, so the register displays the prices like 3.67, 3.66, and so on.

**The values must add up to exactly 100 though** I was thinking of doing this with an epsilon but that wouldn't work.

```
const int divisor = 6;
const int dividend = 10;

std::vector<double> myVec;
myVec.resize(6);

for (int i = 0; i < divisor; ++i)
{
    ...some magic that I don't know how to do
}
```

**EDIT:** The client wants the values stored (and displayed) in values fixed at two decimal places to visually see they add to 100.

Comment: Why does the raw data need to be rounded in this fashion? I imagine grocery store cash registers don't really do this, they probably just store more than 2 digits of precision internally and then round down to 2 on display. And when showing per-item values, it can use the rounding direction of the accumulated total in order to round the specific item. That's certainly how I'd implement such a display.

Comment: You will run into a lot of problems working with `double` here. Consider storing your numbers as cents (so $1.37 is an integer 137), or using a fixed precision number library. Also what happens when the vector is empty?

Comment: @KevinBallard For the application it is preferable that the weights are shown in the decimal format fixed at two decimal places. The client wants to visually add up each of the weights to see if they add to 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide into whatever is left as you go, subtracting the last value from the remaining amount.

```
const int divisor = 6;
const int dividend = 10;

std::vector<double> myVec;
myVec.reserve(6);
double remain = 100.0;

for (int i = divisor; i >= 1; --i)
{
    double val = remain / (double)i;
    remain -= val;
    myVec.push_back(val);
}
```

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks for that.  It's interesting that it does not evenly distribute the error.  I made an alternative: http://ideone.com/2JfIvk

Answer (score 4):

Like the comments say, store money in terms of cents.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

std::vector<int> function(int divisor, int total) {
    std::vector<int> myVec(divisor);
    for (int i = 0; i < divisor; ++i) {
        myVec[i] = total/divisor; //rounding down
        if (i < total%divisor) //for each leftover
           myVec[i] += 1; //add one of the leftovers
    }
    return myVec;
}

void print_dollars(int cents) {
    std::cout << (cents/100) << '.';
    std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (cents%100) << ' ';
}

int main() {
   std::vector<int> r = function(6, 10000);
   int sum=0;
   for(int i=0; i<r.size(); ++i) {
       print_dollars(r[i]);
       sum += r[i];
   }
   std::cout << '\n';
   print_dollars(sum);
}
//16.67 16.67 16.67 16.67 16.66 16.66 
//100.00
```

When you divide 100 by 6, you get 16, with 4 leftover.  This will put those 4 leftover in each of the first four slots of the vector.  Proof of compilation: http://ideone.com/jrInai

Comment: How could I then show this in the output as the fixed decimals?
Like 16.67, 16.66...

Comment: The client wants to be able to see the numbers fixed at two decimal places and to be able to add them visually (strange I know).

Comment: @rem45acp You should work in integers and multiply by 100, then convert to `double` and divide by 100 when you want to display.

Comment: @rem45acp: I added a function that displays the cents as dollars.

Answer (score 2):

There's no one "correct" way to do this. A place to start would be to add up the contents of the vector, and find the difference between 100 and that result you obtained. How you'd fold that in to the individual items would inherently be a heuristic. There are a couple of routes you could take:

1. Add the difference you found divided by the number of elements in the vector to each element in the vector. This has the advantage that it'll affect an individual value by the smallest amount possible in order to achieve your constraint.
2. You might want to just add the difference to the first or last element in the vector. This has the advantage that the fewest number of elements in the vector are modified.
3. You might want to list a separate rounding error element in the vector, which will just be the difference. This gives the most "correct" answer, but might not be what your users want.

Only you can decide what kind of heuristic to use based on the application you're building.

It should be noted that using floating point numbers (e.g. `float`, `double`, and `long double`) may result in errors when storing money values -- you should use fixed point decimal arithmetic for such calculations, because that's how money calculations are done in "the real world". Because floating point uses the base 2 number system internally (on most systems), there will be small rounding errors induced in the conversion from decimal to binary and back. You'll likely have no problem with small values, but if the dollar value is large you'll start seeing problems with the number of digits of precision available in a double.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, 
100/6=16.67 (rounded)
Then you just multiply it by 6-1=5 and get 83.35

And now you know that in order to make the sum to be exactly 100, you need to make the price of the last element to be equal to 
100 -  83.35 = 16.65